# Rename export csv file

Tags: layout, adminhtml, grid, xml, export

Is there a way to rename the default export.csv filename to another filename?
I'm using the magento 2 export in my listing.xml

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I think there is a possibility .Try this,

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/listing.xsd">

    <export entity="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" class="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Adapter\Csv" fileName="custom_export.csv">
        <!-- Other export configuration -->
    </export>

   
</listing>
```

Comment: not working. Error: Element 'export': This element is not expected

```
        <export entity="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" class="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\Adapter\Csv" fileName="custom_export.csv">
                <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        </export>

```

Answer (score 0):

The default Magento hard coded the file name "exported.csv" in this file

vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/GridToCsv.php:70

You can create a composer patch or rewrite this controller by your own for editing the file name

Comment: Can you provide more details? 

```

Comment: I tried this.. but it gives me the Interceptor error.. 
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Thecoachsmb\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToCsv\Interceptor, Argument 1 passed to Thecoachsmb\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToCsv\Interceptor::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2_\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php on line 121

Comment: Because your parameters in the __construct doesn't match the parent class